# Get all player info from XML in PHP file

Tags: php, xml

I have an API from game tracker that I would like to use on my own template. The link of api is: http://api.gametracker.rs/demo/xml/server_info/193.104.68.50:28025/

What I would like to get is all the players in table of PHP, as you can see players_list is a parent of players and child of server_info tag in provided api.

I can get all the info from server_info tag, but unfortunately I cannot parse data from players_list into PHP.

What I tried to do is next:

```
$url = "http://api.gametracker.rs/demo/xml/server_info/217.26.212.10:27015/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->children() as $xml)
{
  $player_id    = $xml->pid;
  $player_name  = $xml->name;
  $player_score = $xml->score;
  $player_time  = $xml->time;
}
```

The point is, I would like to auto update the table and it should look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="number">No.</li>
  <li id="nickname">Nickname</li>
  <li id="score">Score</li>
  <li id="time">Time in game</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have only told what you want. You have not written what your programming question is. No idea how you could get three upvotes for: How to create HTML with PHP which is explained quite near to the first page of the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code below to get array of players:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.gametracker.rs/demo/xml/server_info/217.26.212.10:27015/");

$players = $xml->xpath('//player');
```

And loop through:

```
foreach( $players as $player ) {
    echo "
    <ul>
    <li id=\"number\">$player->pid</li>
    <li id=\"nickname\">$player->name</li>
    <li id=\"score\">$player->score</li>
    <li id=\"time\">$player->time</li>
    </ul>";
    }
```

Comment: That kind of helped me, what i got is full print of:

    Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [pid] => 1 [name] => Djeljana [score] => 0 [time] => 00:08:24 [bot] => 0 ) etc etc...

I don't need "bot" tag, and how can i display it in table, as i have my own styled table... Sorry if i'm questioning to much.

Comment: You don't need to cast to `(array)`, xpath is always returning an array. Very nice and clean solution. +1

Comment: @VladimirCvejic: if you don't need `bot`, simply don't echo it, as shown by Danijel. In your original question, you asked for `<ul><li>`, not `<table>`. Try to put your data into a `<table>` yourself with the code that D. provided, and if you need help, open a new question.

Comment: Great, i got it working, but i have one single problem, when i'm displaying and getting data for players like on this page: http://api.gametracker.rs/demo/xml/server_info/217.26.212.10:20020/

All ID's are 0, what can i do to make it count how many players are there and display it in ID column? Thanks